# Spring Cloud Dataflow | Kafka Binder | Error: KafkaTopicProvisioner - Failed to create topic

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am new in Spring Cloud Dataflow and trying to build a basic stream application with HTTP source, a custom processor and Log Sink. I have written a custom processor that uses JAXB to unmarshall XML records, received from HTTP source, into Java Objects.

Custom Processor:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;


@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProcessorApplication {

    //@Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
    @StreamListener(Processor.OUTPUT)
    @Output(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Object transform(@Payload String xmlstream) {
        try{
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xmlstream));
            Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
            System.out.println(customer);
            return customer;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProcessorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Registered the processor application like this:

```
dataflow:>app register --name myprocessor --type processor --uri file://home/test/scdfCustomApps/processor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Created and deploy the stream like:

```
stream create --name httptest --definition "http --port=9000 | myprocessor | log" --deploy
```

In the processor log, I am seeing the below exceptions:

> 2019-03-21 09:39:50.254 ERROR 10461 --- [ask-scheduler-1]
>   o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner      : Failed to create topics
>
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotControllerException: This is not the
>   correct controller for this cluster.
>
> 2019-03-21 09:39:50.255 ERROR 10461 --- [ask-scheduler-1]
>   o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create producer
>   binding; retrying in 30 seconds
>
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException:
>   Provisioning exception; nested exception is
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotControllerException: This is not the
>   correct controller for this cluster.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any additional configuration needed for registering and
   deploying custom applications?
2. I created another stream 'http | log' which worked fine without any issue. How does these binding happen between source, processor and sink?

**Versions:**
Spring Cloud Dataflow Server : 1.7.3
Spring Cloud : Greenwich.SR1
Kafka Version Installed : 0.10

Comment: Looks like a bug in Kafka - Google `NotControllerException`. 0.10 is very old, but I don't know if it's fixed in more recent versions. I found a discussion [here](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/issues/422) that has a work-around.

Comment: It is not like that Kafka is not at all able to create a topic. When I created the stream 'http | log', even then the binder was Kafka and that worked fine. That brings me to my 2nd Question, how actually does the binding happen between source, processor and sink application in SCDF with Kafka Binder?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; see the [Spring Cloud Stream documentastion](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html). If you still need clarification, please ask a new question with more details about what you don't understand.

Comment: This error occurs on my Sink/Consumer: is it trying to create a topic to store checkpoints during Consumption?  That is my best guess.  Trying to figure this one out.